# Android Studio: How to compile with customized class but still use module dependency

Tags: java, android, compilation, shared-libraries, patch

Say an Android app uses a jar library and everything is working fine when the library is specified as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'org.example:example:1.1.1'
    ...
}
```

**BUT :** one of the classes in the `org.example` code needs to be tweaked.

One approach is to obtain the source code and put all of that in the `java` folder, and remove the module.  When the tweak is made, that, and the entire library will be compiled.

Another approach is to make the tweak, compile, and replace the `.class` file within the `.jar` file.

Both of those methods have their drawbacks.

*My question* is: Is there an easier way to tweak code in a library?

When I tried just creating the package, placing the class that needed changing into the `java` folder, I got an error:

> Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/example/ClassNeedingChange;

I just wondered if there was a trick to getting code in the Java folder to override whats in a library jar file.

*Additional Info:*

Although not stated specifically above, the class that needs tweaking is buried in the library and is referenced by the library's code; I don't call it directly.  For the simple case where the class that needed tweaking is one that my code (and only my code) called directly, then it would be a simple matter of extending the class using the Java construct.  But for this simple case, I would not need to post this question.

Comment: "I just wondered if there was a trick to getting code in the Java folder to override whats in a library jar file." -- remove the class from the JAR file. Though, IMHO, the only maintainable options are the subclass route or forking the library ("obtain the source code..."), though I would put it in a separate module of the project, rather than putting it directly in the project itself.

Comment: Doing that would make future maintenance a pain in the neck.  What if the library changes?  You would have to update this.  You could also compile it locally in gradle, and tell gradle to look for the local version, but that still gives the same maintenance problem

Comment: Create a PR against the lib to give it the behavior you want? Then everyone will benefit.

Comment: What is a "PR"?  I presume you mean ask the owners of the program for a change?  That might be a possibility, but one that would take significant time and effort.

Comment: PR-Pull Request.  Make the change, and submit it in the public repo (assuming it's Open Source) and ask them to pull it in

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm going with the fork approach, but only after I tried and failed to get a class removal scheme to work.  I was able to remove the class from the jar that I added to the project, but I ran into a problem where the class was still around due to pre-dexing, i think (kept getting the `Multiple dex files` problem, even though the class file was certainly not in the main jar, but probably was in classes.dex).

Comment: "where the class was still around due to pre-dexing" -- clean the project (e.g., Build > Clean Project from the Android Studio main menu).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks. I fiddled around cleaning/deleting, but I simply could not keep it from dexing.  I just don't know enough about how that build process works to know where it's getting the classes or source files, and what it's doing and when.  Since I removed the file from the "obvious" jar file and the dex file still ended-up with it, I presume there must be a download going on somewhere.  So the answer to this question (the trick) might be to remove it from the dex file at the appropriate moment in the build process.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the class that needs tweaked in your code, and override the appropriate method.

```
Class A extends TweakMe {

 @Override
 public void someTweakedMethod() {
     //Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work if the class is final or the method private.

Comment: It also won't work if the class that needs tweaking is used from various other parts of the library; those other uses would not know about "A" and would use the default functionality of "TweakMe".